# unable to exit a function in a sourced file

Tags: linux, bash

I have `file1`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source $HOME/file2

answer=$(calculate)
echo "Answer is: $answer"
```

and `file2`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function calculate(){
    local result=$(echo $((RANDOM%2)))
    [ $result -gt 0 ] && exit 1
    echo "$result"  ## this line was missed and was just added
}
```

The problem is `calculate` function never exits, i.e. the line `Answer is:`  gets printed anyway whatever the function output is.
Inserting `set -u` or `set -eu` at the top of both or either of the files was not helpful either.
I have also tried to make it exit using `return 1`, but still no luck.

Comment: `$(echo $((RANDOM%2))` is unnecessary. `[ $((RANDOM%2)) -g t ]` is sufficient.

Comment: That's actually not the point. Even if I remove everything from the function and just leave ```exit```, it won't exit!

Comment: `calculate` does exit, but it exits the subshell created by `$(...)`, not the shell that executes `file1`. `calculate` as defined also never writes any output for `$(...)` to capture anyway.

Comment: @chepner So is there anything that I can do? I want it to exit, or terminate the whole process, before jumping back to ```file1```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture the output of the function, it necessarily has to run in a subshell, which means you'll have to explicitly check the exit status from the caller anyway, so you may as well just return a non-zero value.

```
calculate () {
    local result=$(( RANDOM % 2 ))
    [ "$result" -gt 0 ] || return 1
    echo "$result"
}

answer=$(calculate) || exit 1
```

The exit status of this assignment is the exit status of the command substitution. (And strictly speaking, if you don't use `local`, then `result` will also be defined as a global variable in the subshell of the command substitution, not in your script's environment.)

---

Alternatively, you can let `calculate` set a global variable instead of writing anything to standard output.

```
calculate () {
    answer=$(( RANDOM % 2 ))
    [ "$answer" -gt 0 ] || exit 1
}

calculate
echo "Answer = $answer"
```

Comment: A global variable won't be possible for this case and for some reason I have to use ```local```, but  ```answer=$(calculate) || exit 1``` seems the answer.

Comment: That or `set -eu` both work, but only if you make sure to return success and failure correctly. It didn't work when you tried it because you always returned failure.

Comment: Hi @chepner, I suspect that you answered the question too well.   I don't think nino really wanted the program to stop running (exit).  I think nino was just trying to return a value.

Comment: Yeah, in context, I think the exit status itself is sufficient.

Comment: @Mark Actually, the calculate function has to decide whether A: provide an output (here being "0"), or B: terminate the whole process. The point is this decision has to made **within** the function, not after that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses exit codes, but doesn't call exit.

File1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source $HOME/file2

calculate
echo "Answer is: $?"
```

Please note the substantial difference here - I am *calling* calculate directly.  I am ignoring stdout from calculate but rather just capturing the exit status: $?.

And File2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function calculate(){
    local result=$(echo $((RANDOM%2)))
     [ $result -gt 0 ] 
}
```

In file2, the status returned from calculate is the status of the last command executed.  Test ([]) returns 0 for true and 1 for false.  So if $result is greater than 0, a 0 will be returned (which is the opposite of what you want).  Come to think of it, here's something more like what you were looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function calculate(){
    local result=$(echo $((RANDOM%2)))
     ! [ $result -gt 0 ] 
}
```

The big change in calculate() is that the exit code from the last command executed is being used to produce the exit status of the function.  If you use exit in a function you call directly, the exit will terminate your calling shell immediately.